# How to Create Scrollable popup window on Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, popup, adt

How to Create Scrollable popup window on Android? 
Here is my code with popup please can someone help me with scrollable popup window.

Please help me with scrollable window.

Comment: your code dint popup here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Create a custom layout for popup (xml file)

Example code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alertbox_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_black"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:weightSum="100"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/alertbox_yes"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="48"
            android:background="@color/navigation_item_background"
            android:text="@string/alertbox_yes"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color_black"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/alertbox_no"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="48"
            android:background="#808080"
            android:text="@string/alertbox_no"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

2. Call this popup in your activity wherever required

Example code:

```
public void showAlertbox(String title) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alertbox_yes_no);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        TextView alertbox_title = (TextView) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.alertbox_title);
        alertbox_title.setText(title);

        Button yes = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.alertbox_yes);
        Button no = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.alertbox_no);

        yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //code the functionality when YES button is clicked
            }
        });

        no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //code the functionality when NO button is clicked
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot DsD...!!

Comment: Great it helped you! If it has solved your problem, mark the answer as 'Accepted' so it helps others too ;)!!

Comment: My reputation point below 15 so its not allowing me to do so...`!!!

Comment: Ok no probs...glad it solved your problem :)!